# java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server

Tags: java, weblogic

I encountered the following issue when running program in Weblogic server.

The url **http://localhost:8080** is reachable on my side, but when I use the below code to connect the server it failed with connection exception.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;

public static String invokeGet(String url, String dsl) {
  String url = "http://localhost:8080";
  Client clientInstance = Client.create();
  clientInstance.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("", ""));

  WebResource webResource = clientInstance.resource(url);

  ClientResponse response =
    webResource.entity(dsl).header("Content-type", "application/json").accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
     }
```

The detailed error message:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'hostname', port: '8080'

at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:333)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:425)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:252)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:213)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:398)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:37)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1005)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:215)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:126)
    ... 182 more
```

**One more thing is that I can run it normally in integrated server but failed to run it in standalone server.**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like ovveriding config property defaultzone on the server.
Probably you will find solution here:

Comment: [LINK](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1305)

> After days, looking thousand times on the same config file I realized the issue. At the end it was just a misspelling of defaultzone. After changing it to defaultZone everything works like expected.
>   Thank you very much for your time.